# Returning IEnumerable with an anonymous type

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an interface similar to this:

```
IEnumerable<(string valueA, decimal valueB)> GetData
```

This interface should not be changed. So I'm trying to implement it. I need to use LINQ, so I have this part of code:

```
var fetchedData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                    .Skip(1)
                    .Select(a => x.Split(';'))
                    .Select(a => new 
                    {
                        valueB= decimal.Parse(a[0]),
                        valueA= a[1]
                    });
return fetchedData;
```

The problem is that `fetchedData` is not of the same type the interface expects. I need to return `IEnumerable<(string valueA, decimal valueB)>` but `fetchedData` is another type.

Comment: Why don't you use tuple then? `.Select(a => (a[1], decimal.Parse(a[0]));`

Comment: Then make it the correct type: `.Select(a => (valueA: a[1], valueB: decimal.Parse(a[0]))`. Note the different syntax for anonymous types and value tuples; your `IEnumerable` declaration uses the latter. Adding the member names is optional here, but I'd highly recommend it, as it makes it much more clear that the order needs to be respected (unlike with anonymous types).

Comment: You cannot return an anonymous type. You can however return a `Tuple`

Comment: `(string valueA, decimal valueB)` is not an anonymous type, it's a tuple.

Comment: @hunter44 Btw, maybe better use a library to parse your CSV...  No need to re-invent the wheel.

Answer (score 3):

Just return a named tuple in your select, instead of an anonymous object :)

```
IEnumerable<(string valueA, decimal valueB)> GetData()
    => File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
           .Skip(1)
           .Select(a => a.Split(';')) // here, you used x instead of a
           .Select(a => (valueA: a[1], valueB: decimal.Parse(a[0])));
```

Comment: I rolled backed your changes to the question as I felt you imparted a sense that the OP knew what they were doing - which they didn't. The original question gave more context.

Answer (score 3):

You are confusing [Anonymous Types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/fundamentals/types/anonymous-types) and [Value Tuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/value-tuples) here.

While your interface returns a tuple, your LINQ query yields an anonymous type. Change your query to:

```
var fetchedData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
    .Skip(1)
    .Select(a => x.Split(';'))
    .Select(a => (a[1], decimal.Parse(a[0])));
```

Answer (score 3):

There are a few issues with your code:

1. Your interface expects the result to be a `Tuple<string, decimal>` which is the actual type behind the notation `(string valueA, decimal valueB)`
2. Your code, particularly the following line:

   ```
   .Select(a => new 
       {
           valueB= decimal.Parse(a[0]),
           valueA= a[1]
       })
   ```

   produces an anonymous object with the following fields `{ decimal valueB; string valueA; }`. The problem is that the .NET will declare a class to represent the anonymous type, and that is incompatible with the Tuple type you initially request from the interface.

Here is a fix for your code that should satisfy the interface:

```
var fetchedData = File.ReadAllLines(filePath)
                .Skip(1)
                .Select(a => x.Split(';'))
                .Select(a => (a[1], decimal.Parse(a[0]) ) );
return fetchedData;
```

Answer (score 2):

If the interface insist on *tuple* (named tuple), let's provide it:

```
return File            // let's drop fetchedData and just return 
  .ReadLines(filePath) // Let's drop All - premature materialization
  .Skip(1)
  .Select(a => x.Split(';'))
  .Select(a => (a[1], decimal.Parse(a[0]));
```

All you have to do is to change `{..}` into `(...)` and keep the right order (first `string` than `decimal`). You may want to put the names, but it's *not required*:

```
return File
  .ReadLines(filePath)
  .Skip(1)
  .Select(a => x.Split(';'))
  .Select(a => (valueA : a[1], valueB : decimal.Parse(a[0]));
```